# FullCalendar - Adding Multiple Events or Add Event Source

Tags: java, jquery, fullcalendar

I have looked through the post in stackoverflow to add events into FullCalendar, however I am really new and find it really difficult to understand without an example. In short, is anyone here able to dumb it down for me, in order to add an array of objects into the FullCalendar?

I would like to add appointments that I have created Appointment(Date date, String name, String phoneNo). So they are retrieved in list:

```
 PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
 String query = "select from " + Appointment.class.getName();  
 query += " where merchant == '" + session.getAttribute("merchant") + "'";
 List<Appointment> appointment = (List<Appointment>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
```

How am I able to populate the FullCalendar plugin with the list I obtained? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have looked through http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ as well, but doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Alright, if anyone is wondering too, from the list you can convert them to JSON objects. It is done this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332733/how-to-convert-list-data-into-json-in-java. If you're new to JSON like me, you can download the jar file and insert into your library via here: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/. Will update more soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if anyone encounters the same problem as I do - you have a list of java objects and want it to populate FullCalendar, here's the solution:

**JSP Page**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                    selectable: true,
                    selectHelper: true,

                select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                        if (title) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                            {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                allDay: allDay
                            },
                            true // make the event "stick"
                            );
                            }
                            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                        },
                                editable: true,

                                eventSources: [
                                    {
                                            url: '/calendarDetails',
                                            type: 'GET',
                                            data: {
                                                start: 'start',
                                                end: 'end',
                                                id: 'id',
                                                title: 'title',
                                                allDay: 'allDay'
                                            },
                                            error: function () {
                                                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                                            }
                                    }
                            ]         
                    });
            });
```

Please take not of the URL, it is the servlet URL

**Servlet**

```
    public class CalendarServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws IOException {

        String something = req.getSession().getAttribute("merchant").toString(); //get info from your page (e.g. name) to search in query for database

        //Get the entire list of appointments available for specific merchant from database

        //Convert appointment to FullCalendar (A class I created to facilitate the JSON)
        List<FullCalendar> fullCalendar = new ArrayList<FullCalendar>();
        for (Appointment a : appointment) {
            String startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(a.getDate());
            startDate = startDate.replace(" ", "T");

            //Calculate End Time
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(a.getDate());
            c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 60);
            String endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(c.getTime());
            endDate = endDate.replace(" ", "T");

            FullCalendar fc = new FullCalendar(startDate, endDate, a.getId(), a.getName() + " @ " + a.getPhone(), false);
            fullCalendar.add(fc);
        }

        //Convert FullCalendar from Java to JSON
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonAppointment = gson.toJson(fullCalendar);

        //Printout the JSON
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        try {
            resp.getWriter().write(jsonAppointment);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

if you need more info on JSON or GSON, check the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Melvin you have tones of examples here in Stack, try searching for add event sources.

From my experience im fullcalendar, you can add events through JSON, well formed XML and array's and i think thats it. You can use ajax calls do retrieve does 3 types of formats.

In your server side you should create a method to return a String already with the XML/JSON/array built  so you can pass to you ajax call.

Comment: thanks for the response, so you mean that I cannot simply use the java List i have (i.e. Appointment), and have to add the events through JSON?

Comment: That's it you cannot just simply pass the Java List you have to transforme that List into an acceptable fullcalendar format( JSON,XML,Array ). If you are messing with Java in your servlet return the string already done or you can have a file myfile.json, i see there are some examples already in this question, but if you need another let me know ;)...

Comment: Hi Henrique, thanks a lot. I have converted the List to JSON, updated the question in case anyone else is wondering too. So I understand that I have to have a JSON feed page in order for the FullCalendar to work? i shall research on it a little more before bothering you guys :)

Comment: the website (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) states that I need to fetch the events from a JSON feed. Is it possible that the feed is on the same page, and not a separate page ?

Comment: if a separate page is a must, anyone has any idea how to create a php with the information i have in my <appointment> java array?

Comment: Hi Melvin

You don´t need to have a separate file for the feed, like i said, in your servlet in your "_**response**_" writer, pass the string with the format.

In my case i append to a string the JSON then i send back in the response like so: 

`Printwriter outstuff = response.writer();` 
`String sb = new String();`

`sb+= "[";`
`sb+={"title":"titlevalue","start":"starvalue"....etc};`
`sb+="]";`

`outstuff.print(sb);`
etc...

Comment: is it something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837241/events-not-loading-jquery-full-calendar-java-integration ? omg thanks! I shall go try it now!

Comment: Hi Henrique, I have got it to work and posted my solution for anyone who needs it in future. Thanks a lot for the inspiration and help, I almost gave up on it.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://github.com/mzararagoza/rails-fullcalendar-icecube 
this is done in rails  but i think what you are looking for is

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
          document.location.href=new_event_link + "?start_date=" + date;
},
```

full jquery

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
          document.location.href=new_event_link + "?start_date=" + date;
        },
          header: {
              left: 'prev,today,next',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          selectable: true,
          selectHelper: true,
          editable: false,
          ignoreTimezone: false,
          select: this.select,
          eventClick: this.eventClick,
          eventDrop: this.eventDropOrResize,
          eventSources: [
            {
                url: '/event_instances.json',
                data: {
                    custom_param1: 'something',
                    custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                }
            }
          ],

          eventResize: this.eventDropOrResize
      });
```